# Vimeo API: Play button and multiple videos

Tags: javascript, api, playback, vimeo

I'm having some trouble. I just discovered that you can control vimeo with js, and now I'm trying to create a play button that will start playing a vimeo video.

The problem I'm having is that I have multiple videos on the same page. I took the example/playground file (from here http://player.vimeo.com/playground / https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript) and removed the functionality that I don't require, however, I can't understand how I connect the play button with a certain video.

This is what I have so far

HTML:

```
<iframe id="player_1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/7100569?api=1&amp;player_id=player_1" width="540" height="304" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<div class="intro">
     <span class="hide">Play 1</span>
</div>
<iframe id="player_2" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/7100569?api=1&amp;player_id=player_2" width="540" height="304" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<div class="intro">
    <span class="hide">Play 2</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
            var vimeoPlayers = document.querySelectorAll('iframe'),
                player;

            for (var i = 0, length = vimeoPlayers.length; i < length; i++) {
                player = vimeoPlayers[i];
                $f(player).addEvent('ready', ready);
            }


            function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
                if (element.addEventListener) {
                    element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
                }
                else {
                    element.attachEvent(eventName, callback, false);
                }
            }


            function ready(player_id) {
                // Keep a reference to Froogaloop for this player
                var container = document.getElementById(player_id).parentNode.parentNode,
                    froogaloop = $f(player_id);

                function setupSimpleButtons() {
                    var buttons = container.querySelector('div.intro'),
                        playBtn = buttons.querySelector('.hide');

                    // Call play when play button clicked
                    addEvent(playBtn, 'click', function() {
                        froogaloop.api('play');
                    }, false);



                }

                setupSimpleButtons();
            }
        })();
```

If I have code that is unnecessary please help me remove it.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ready()` function is called once per vimeo player.  You need to change which object is hooked up with the addEvent button.  To do this you probably need to put `id` attributes on the buttons themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this much easier, you can see an example here:
http://labs.funkhausdesign.com/examples/vimeo/froogaloop2-api-basics.html